# C++ ambiguous overload

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Consider the following:

```
#include <string>

template <typename T, 
    typename std::enable_if<(
        std::is_integral<T>::value 
        && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value
    )>::type = 0>
void add(T val)
{
}

void add(bool val)
{
}

void add(const char* val)
{
}

int main()
{
    add(true);
    add("hi");
    add(0);
}
```

The compiler complains that `add(0);` is ambiguous:

> [x86-64 clang 6.0.0 #1] error: call to 'add' is ambiguous

I figure this because `0` is implicitly convertible to `bool` or `const char*`. However, I would like the compiler to pick the templated method without having to cast the `0` (ie. `add((int)0);`) or specifying the templated type (ie. `add<int>(0);`).

I have also tried changing the template signature to:

```
template <typename T, 
    typename std::enable_if<(
        std::is_integral<T>::value 
        && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value
        && !std::is_same<T, unsigned char>::value
    )>::type = 0>
void add(T val)
...
```

But that doesn't help either. How can I get this to work the way I want?

Thanks!

Comment: @OlivierSohn I've completely misread the question. :/

Answer (score 5):

`enable_if` has a 2nd template parameter, which defaults to `void`, and defines the `type` when the condition is `true`.  `typename void = 0` doesn't compile, this is why the function could not be part of overload resolution. However `typename int = 0` does compile, so passing `int` makes the function be part of overload reolution:

```
template <typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<(
        std::is_integral<T>::value 
        && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value
        && !std::is_same<T, unsigned char>::value
    ), int>::type = 0>
void add(T val)
{
}
```

You can also write it like that, without passing the second parameter, it's simpler I think:

```
template <typename T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<(
        std::is_integral<T>::value 
        && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value
    )>::type>
void add(T val)
{
}

void add(bool val)
{
}

void add(const char* val)
{
}

int main()
{
    add(true);
    add("hi");
    add(0);       // A
    add<int>(0);  // B
    // A and B call the same function
}
```

Comment: Sure, but is there a way to do it implicitly? I've updated the question.

Comment: @Oliver What if I don't want to use `enable_if` as part of the return type? Why does it not work otherwise?

Comment: @Addy I edited my answer to explain what the problem was, more precisely. Please take a look. I also provide a solution where you don't need to use `enable_if` as part of the result type.

Comment: another alternative could be `typename std::enable_if<(std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value)>::type * = nullptr>`

Comment: @max66 I didn't think of that, that's a nice way of doing it, too!